# using bgr2gray in python are not modifing to gray

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale

I am importing an image in python using `opencv` and trying to change it to grayscale, but it won't change and it returns back in a hue like colors

```py
def grayscale(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return img

img = grayscale(X_train[1000])
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis("off")
```

Comment: Did you load the image by opencv (cv2.imread) or another library? The conversion works for me

Comment: Also, what is X_train? what is its shape?

Comment: i am using an image data set and this is the number of image

Comment: the shape is (32,32,3)

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FX3WR8EtEUk1ZuxEzIHixFkDY6sUlSair6M3VuUNOq8XsClZgjLbAKIhdhoyjwKLnzj3FQw=s86

Comment: Make sure that the shape of `img` in the method is what you expect

Answer (score 0):

You're converting the gray correctly. The 'hue like' colors you're seeing are the result of `plt.imshow()` using a default palette for a two-dimensional image. It's surprising the first time you run into it. The reason why matplotlib behaves like this is hinted at in the [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) documentation.

Try

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```